# I have 3 users with different id in the database and it keeps getting the last user id that been loop when I accept or reject?

Tags: php

There are 3 id that been view from this table

```
$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM user_appointment WHERE event = '' ");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){

    $id = $row["id"];

    $date = $row["date"];

    $office = $row['office'];

        echo "<table>";

            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td colspan='2'> <strong>Name: </strong>" . $row['first_name'] . " "  . $row['middle_name'] . " " . $row['last_name'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td><strong>You're request is: </strong>" . $row['event'] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            
            echo "<tr><td colspan='3'> <strong>Address: </strong>" . $row['address'] . " </td></tr>";
            echo "<tr><td colspan='3'> <strong>Office to go: </strong>" . $row['office'] . " </td></tr>";

            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td> <strong>Contact#: </strong>" . $row['phone'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td> <strong>Request made from: </strong>" . $row['curdate'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td> <strong>Time request: </strong>" . $row['time'] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";

            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td colspan='3'><strong><i>Message: </i></strong><br>". $row['message'] . "</td>";                
            echo "</tr>";
        
            echo "<tr> <td colspan='3'>";
                echo "<center><form method='GET'>
                        <div class='center'>
                            <label for=''>Select Date:</label><br>
                            <input type='date' name='userDate' id='userDate' value='' required>
                        </div><br>
                            <button type='submit' name='approveSubmit' class='btn btn-success'>ACCEPT</button>
                            <button type='submit' name='rejectSubmit' class='btn btn-danger'>REJECT</button>";
                echo "</form> </center>";
            echo "</td></tr>";

        echo "</table>";

        echo 'Either I choose one of the users, it still getting the user id that been loop last';

        if(isset($_GET['approveSubmit'])){
            isset($_GET['userDate']);
            $date = $_GET['userDate'];
            
            header("location: ../approve_insert.php?id=$id&date=$date");
        }
        if(isset($_GET['rejectSubmit'])){
            header("location: ../reject_insert.php?id=$id");
        }                                          
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not passing the correct `$id` to your `header: Location(..`.
To solve this you would need to pass the id of the user to the form as well, so this value become available when an user is clicked.

You can do this by adding an extra hidden input to the form you are creating

```html
<input type='hidden' name='id' value='".$id."' />
```

Also there is no need to place the code that controls the action you want to do inside the loop that creates the table. Just place it above (or below) the code that generates the table

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['approveSubmit'])){
        $date = $_GET['userDate'];
        header('location: ../approve_insert.php?id='.$_GET['id'].'&date='.$date);
        exit;
    }

    if(isset($_GET['rejectSubmit'])){
        header('location: ../reject_insert.php?id='.$_GET['id']);
        exit;
    }

    $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM user_appointment WHERE event = '' ");

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){
        $id = $row["id"];
        $date = $row["date"];
        $office = $row['office'];
        echo '... table start ...';

        echo "<center><form method='GET'>
                <div class='center'>
                    <label for=''>Select Date:</label><br>
                    <input type='date' name='userDate' id='userDate' value='' required>
                </div><br>

                <button type='submit' name='approveSubmit' class='btn btn-success'>ACCEPT</button>
                <button type='submit' name='rejectSubmit' class='btn btn-danger'>REJECT</button>
                <input type='hidden' name='id' value='".$id."' />
                ";
        echo "</form> </center>";
        echo '... table end ...';
    }
```

---

Keep in my mind you would still need to sanitize the input of `$_GET['id']` and `$_GET['userDate']` *before* using it in your code/queries

Answer (score -1):

My assumption at this point is that multiple users meet the conditions at the end of your loop. If your goal is to redirect to the location specified, from the first header location call, you'd have to prevent the loop from continuing. Typically this would be done with `exit()`.

```
header("location: ../reject_insert.php?id=$id");
exit();
```

Also, you're going to get an error that you can't set headers because you've already output body content. The `header("location...")` can only be called before your `echo ...` statements.

Comment: This is incorrect, OP is using the last value of the loop stored in `$id`, rather than passing the correct user id he/she selected

Comment: I agree that's what is happening. I'm suggesting that is not what OP is trying to do.

Comment: while this is true, this does not solve OP's problem